# How to configure SONAR setting for intellij sonar plugin for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I have installed the SONAR plugin for Android studio. I would like to have the following features, if possible

1. I want to be able to configure the rules of SONAR.
2. I also want to switch on/off the sonar lint check. As of now, the SONAR lint is always on, and its slows down the ide sometimes.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Where do I get access to the SonarQube rules in Android Studio for the plugin? I know how it is done using a sonar-runner.

Comment: I am talking about the intellij plugin for Android Studio. Running Sonar on a project and seeing the report on browser is something totally of different context.

Comment: any progress on this? I am looking for a way to exclude specific Sonar rule related to Activities inheritance (squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth) which is by default set to 5 and AppCompatActivity already step over that number